# Requested service is temporarily unavailable on IIS server

Tags: php, ssl, iis, moodle

We are configured Moodle on IIS server. When we access application using domain sometimes we are getting

```
"The requested service is temporarily unavailable. It is either overloaded or under maintenance. Please try later."
```

We are using Moodle 3.1 and PHP 7.1 and a new server with 8GB RAM.

How we can solve this problem?. Any help appreciated.

Some thoughts in my mind to cause this issue:

1. Network issue
2. PHP setting issue (php.ini)
3. Server config issue
4. SSL certificate issue OR https setup issue.

**Edit:**

If we setup localhost and access inside windows azure server it is working fine. But from remote if we try to access application using https domain giving this error.

Comment: Have you checked your IIS error log, or the application event logs?

Comment: Yes. I didn't get any clue.

Comment: Try https:// if http:// fails.